# How to avoid occurence in Squish for Qt testing?

Tags: squish

I am working on Qt GUI testing in Squish (Python). I am facing many dynamic objects (many occurences for every execution). How to avoid the occurrence in Squish?

Comment: please take a look [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the application GUI design at that point, and whether there is a [memory leak](https://kb.froglogic.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=131141) that causes the ["occurrence" property](https://kb.froglogic.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=131141) in the Squish object real name for the respective GUI object.

In general the best is to use [QObject.setObjectName(QString)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) to [assign a (good, unique enough) name to each GUI object](https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Article+-+Explicitly+Naming+Objects) that your GUI automation test script needs to interact with.

If this has been done, and there is no object real name that identifies the object in the object map yet, then a new Squish object name will get added to the object map when interacting with the object, and this new object name will have a "name" property with the value set via QObject.setObjectName(QString) for that object, and likely not the "occurrence" property.

Answer (score 1):

Occurence is used to identify objects that does not have enough unique attributes to difderentiate from each other.

For example, if you have a label with the same caption/text, but no unique name assigned to it, then Squish will identify the second label with occurence=1 attribute. This is not maintainable in the long run since any modification to the object steucture might make the script invalid, script will identify objects wrongly if occurence changes.

What I did was requesting to **assign a unique name** for each GUI control from the developer side. When there is a unique name for each object, Squish will not use 'occurence' but identify the object using that 'name' and most probably with 'type' and 'visible' attributes together.